# Excel Vba split multiple cells into columns

Tags: excel, vba, text-to-column

My file has multiple lines (72000+) written like this:

```
UNIX timestamp;User id;In/Out
```

This homework is about a parking lot. My problem is how do I split all col A into 3 other cols (like B, C and D). I found the split function but I not understanding how to do a loop that cycles all rows and split the text to the other columns .

Comment: Please provide some code. What have you tried so far? What do expect your code to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: You don't have to use code - Look under Data, Text to Columns, Delimited and tick comma

Comment: @HarassedDad, those delimiters look like semi-colons.

Comment: You could try something like this `Range(input your range here).TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, semicolon:=True` using vba to split the data into three columns or use the Text to Columns function under the Data tab.

Comment: If using Text to Columns, you will have to change the target from A1 (the defalt) to B1 in order to fill columns B, C and D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data starts in cell **A1**:

```
Sub Parser()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A:A")
        If cell.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
        Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3)).Value = Split(cell, ";")
    Next cell
End Sub
```